# How does one use an IndexedTraversal in Control.Lens to perform an index-aware action for each element?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I have an [`IndexedTraversal`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html#t%3aIndexedTraversal) (from the [`Control.Lens`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) package) and I would like to apply an index-aware monadic action to each element in it.  Unfortunately, all of the convenient ways that I see of doing something like this --- such as [`^!`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Control-Lens-Action.html#v%3a-94--33-) combined with [`act`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Control-Lens-Action.html#v%3aact) function --- seem to ignore the index with each element.  Is there a nice way to run an action for every element (and its index) in an indexed traversal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does [imapMOf](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-3.10/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html#v:imapMOf) work?  You would use it as `imapMOf someIndexedTraversal actionWithIndex dataStructure` I think.

If you just need to perform an action, there's also [imapMOf_](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-3.10/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v:imapMOf_) in `Control.Lens.Fold`.

I haven't used indexed traversals much, but I find the API a bit confusing.  Most of the time I use lenses with either `^.` or `^!`, but for indexed traversals it seems the usual way is to use one of the special index-aware functions, which seems a bit different.

Comment: You can also use Control.Lens.Indexed.withIndex to get a traversal over tuples of (index, value), with some limitations. But using imapMOf and the other i<something> combinators is more convenient in most cases, I would think.